# Карусель товаров в woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как можно осуществить вывод новых или популярных товаров в карусель? Товары выведены с помощью шорткода [image: вывод на главной] [image: шорткод]

Нужно поместить товары в карусель, чтобы можно было листать и посмотреть все. Пытался установить slick slider и сделать с помощью него - безуспешно. Думаю что я неправильно его подключил[image: functions.php]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не хватает инициализации слайдера

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.pop-carousel .products').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    });
});
```

В WordPress нужно писать JS код и инициализировать библиотеки с использованием [jQuery.noConflict();](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Инициализировал в файле app.js.

Comment: Какие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'   в файлу slick.css

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function       в  app.js:1

Comment: Обновил код и добавил комментарий. Скиньте ссылку на сайт

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в инициализации вот правильный код:

`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {  $('.new-carousel .products').slick({ slidesToShow: 4, slidesToScroll: 12, dots: true, }); });`

Comment: Ну так это и есть то, что я вам написал. На вашем скрине нет класса .new-carousel, это вы уже в процессе поменяли, хотя не понятно зачем. Все остальное это дополнительные параметры

Comment: Прошу прощения не заметил